# iOS __autoreleasing const error

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

So I'm doing the usual where I'm passing a pointer to an NSError object to a method.  It used to be a simple:

```
-(BOOL)foo:(NSString *)string error:(NSError **)error
```

but with ARC it is now:

```
-(BOOL)foo:(NSString *)string error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
```

So if I have a variable:

```
NSError *error = nil;
```

and attempt:

```
[foo:@"a string" error:&error];
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Sending 'NSError const __strong*' to parameter of type 'NSError *__autoreleasing*' changes retain/release properties of pointer.
```

That's fine, even though I was under the impression that the compiler would handle this for you.  So I make error:

```
__autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;
```

and I get the warning:

```
Sending 'NSError *__autoreleasing const *' to parameter of type 'NSError *__autoreleasing*' discards qualifier
```

So my real question is why is my NSError a const?  And my next question is how do I fix this?  This is a very basic situation here, and with now with ARC I'm just not sure how to take care of this.

Answer (score 4):

You can see in the Apple headers that there is no need for the __autoreleasing in the interface description (ie look at the header file for NSFileManager attributesOfFileSystemForPath). So use:

```
(NSError **)
```

instead of

```
(NSError *__autoreleasing *)
```

EDIT: I have a sample project I play with, that has ARC enabled in it, and I just did this with no problems:

```
-(BOOL)foo:(NSString *)string error:(NSError **)error
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    __autoreleasing NSError *err = nil;
    [self foo:@"glop" error:&err];
    NSLog(@"%@", err);
```

Compiles just fine.

Comment: this is bizarre.  it won't let me do this.  even if i change the parameter name to something else, if it sees an NSError pointer coming in, it won't allow it, and is giving me the original error.

Comment: You changed the interface AND the implementation, right? I'll go test it now in a sample project...

Comment: i just built a similar project, and it works fine.  somehow i must be missing something, but i can't see what it is.  i'll look some more...  oh, and i didn't even use __autoreleasing and it still compiled without error.

Comment: guess the whole picture is necessary:-)  this was in a block.  declaring __block NSError *error = nil; fixed this...

Comment: __autoreleasing is necessary when source code is in ARC. The reason why you are not getting any errors is because you are not assigning any error's value in the function -foo for the double pointer passed as argument.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in XCode 4.4:

```
- (BOOL) foo: (NSString*) string error: (out NSError *__autoreleasing *) outError;
```

Comment: i'm on 4.3.3, and this doesn't change anything.  i must be doing something here, i can't believe this isn't a major issue, and yet i found almost nothing googling this.